# making variable with the values of another variable in unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix

**I need to make variable using two other variable values.**

```
#i have two variable in unix i.e.#
v_a=a
v_b=b
##now i want to combine the two values of the two variable and the result of that i want that as a variable means v_a_b and use it.##
echo 'v_'$v_a'_'$v_b #the output will be v_a_b and i want to use it like $v_a_b
```

Comment: $v_a_b is a variable that i want to use further in my code.

Comment: What should be the value of `$v_a_b`? Did you check Walter's answer below?

Comment: you can give any value to $v_a_b i want to use this in further block of my code. Yeah with eval i can to this.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have the following vars:

```
v_a=a
v_b=b
v_a_b="I want this one"
v_a_c="Wrong one!"
```

How do you get `I want this one` using the values of `v_a` and `v_b` ?
You can use eval, but try to avoid that:

```
# don't do this
eval echo "\$v_${v_a}_${v_b}"
```

You need a new variable , lets call it `c` and get the value of the constructed var:

```
c="v_${v_a}_${v_b}"
echo "Using the exclamation mark for retrieving the valueCombined: ${!c}"
```

Another way is using `printf`:

```
printf -v c "v_%s_%s" "${v_a}"  "${v_b}"
echo "Combined: ${!c}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use eval to explicitly pre-evaluate an expression.
for your question,

```
eval 'echo \$v_"$v_a"_"$v_b"'
```

should work fine,
`echo \$v_"$v_a"_"$v_b"` evaluates to `echo $v_a_b`, then the intermediate result is evaluated again, so in effect, we get the result of `$(echo $v_a_b)`
note: you might want to quote the variable `$v_a_b`:

```
eval 'echo \"\$v_"$v_a"_"$v_b"\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to concatenate the contents of variables `v_a` and `v_b` (along with some fixed strings 'v_' and '_') then store it in a variable named `v_a_b`.

```
v_a=a
v_b=b
v_a_b='v_'$a'_'$b
echo $v_a_b
```

The output is `v_a_b`.

Comment: no this i don't want to do. I want to make a new variable with the result of two variables and then use it like result will be v_a_b and i want to use $v_a_b.

Answer (score 0):

```
   v_a=a
   v_b=b
   v_a_b=c
   eval V_XYZ='$'"v_"$v_a"_"$v_b
   echo 'Value= '$V_XYZ
```

output will be c